# Update PysimpleGUI window with values from Excel sheet

Tags: pandas, dataframe, user-interface, populate, pysimplegui

I am trying to reference a Pandas dataframe in Pysimplegui

`

```
# function definitions
def retrieve_info():
    if values['-UPC-'] == '':
        search_box = values['-UPC-']
        records = item_info.iloc[item_info[0] == search_box]
        for records in records:
            window['-SKU-'].update(records[item_info['Item Number']])
            window['-DESCRIPTION-'].update(records[item_info['Item Description']])
            window['-UOM-'].update(records[item_info['UOM']])
            window['-LOCATION-'].update(records[item_info['LOCATION']])
```

`

trying to get the fields below Scan Product to populate with information but instead get this error. KeyError: 'UPC'
[image: GUI]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `search_box` will be an empty string. Search where the string `'UPC'` in your script and find what's the correct key.

Comment: Yes its currently empty however, the idea is when the user scans a UPC from a product into the field Scan Product: then the other inputs will return a value from the excel that is uploaded into the GUI.  UPC in the excel document is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Demo code for you

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg


# table = pd.read_excel('table.xlsx')
data = [[(i+1)*(j+1) for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[i+1 for i in range(9)])

layout = [
    [sg.Text("A (1~9)"), sg.Input(size=5, enable_events=True, key='A')],
    [sg.Text("B (1~9)"), sg.Input(size=5, enable_events=True, key='B')],
    [sg.Text(f"A x B = ", expand_x=True, key='Result')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in 'AB':
        a, b = values['A'], values['B']
        if a and a in "123456789" and b and b in "123456789":
            window['Result'].update(f'{a} x {b} = {table[int(a)][int(b)-1]}')
        else:
            window['Result'].update('Wrong A or B')


window.close()
```

[image]

There's nothing special for the table.xlsx, it is something like this.
[image]

Comment: thanks jason do you happen to have the excel table you used so i can see how it works.

Comment: There's nothing special for the xlsx file, top row for the columns, updated as above.